# How to check if a user document exists in Flutter Firestore?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to add a check after a user is authenticated if a user has a document in Firestore under a 'users' collection based on their UserID ('uid') via a StreamBuilder.

The issue I have is when I run my code, it works as intended but after a few seconds, it redirects to the 'UserHomeScreen' even if the document does not exist. How can I rectify this so a user without a user document does not get pushed to my 'UserHomeScreen'?

Here is my code:

```
class UserStream extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserStream({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc('uid').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return const UserHomeScreen();
        } else {
          return const SignUpNewUser();
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `snapshot.hasData` is true when the asynchronous call has completed. Even when the document doesn't exist, `snapshot.hasData` will still be true once that has been determined.

To ensure the document exists, you'll also want to check:

```
if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists) {
  ...
```

This is also shown in the documentation on [handling one time reads](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#one-time-read).